# How to create auto text size for all screen sizes?

Tags: android

I have used

```
app:autoSizeTextType
app:autoSizeMaxTextSize 
app:autoSizeMinTextSize
```

properties and given same properties for 2 textviews but text sizes vary according to their contents. If content is small then font size increases and if content is large the font size decreases.

```
app:autoSizeTextType
app:autoSizeMaxTextSize
app:autoSizeMinTextSize
```

Comment: Can you provide the XML code you `TextView`? You should **NOT** be using `wrap_content` in width or height otherwise it will produce unexpected results.

Answer (score 1):

[**`Autosizing TextViews`**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview)

> With Android 8.0 (API level 26) and higher, you can instruct a
>   TextView to let the text size expand or contract automatically to fill
>   its layout based on the TextView's characteristics and boundaries.
>   This setting makes it easier to optimize the text size on different
>   screens with dynamic content.

- You should set static ***`android:layout_height`*** value.
- Set the **autoSizeText** attribute to either none or uniform. none is a
  default value and uniform lets TextView scale uniformly on horizontal
  and vertical axes.
- Set **autoSizeMinTextSize**, **autoSizeMaxTextSize**, and
  **autoSizeStepGranularity** attributes to define the dimensions for the
  autosizing of TextView.

Your XML will be

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
    android:autoSizeMinTextSize="12sp"
    android:autoSizeMaxTextSize="100sp"
    android:autoSizeStepGranularity="2sp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library it can easily manage your requirements.

**Here is the** [Library](https://github.com/grantland/android-autofittextview)

**In XML you can use like this**

```
<me.grantland.widget.AutofitTextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:maxLines="2"
    android:textSize="40sp"
    autofit:minTextSize="16sp"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement style for each one and just set required style for each one.
For example, you can inherit the Android platform's default text appearance and modify it as follows:

```
<style name="GreenText" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">#00FF00</item>
</style>
```

and set the style for text view

```
<TextView
    style="@style/GreenText"
    android:text="android:textColorPrimary"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

only you use dynamic sizes:

in app\src\main\res you must create below folders:

[image]

and in each folder create dimens.xml (for example):

now come back to the android studio:

[image]

add below code in each xml file:

in small

```
    <dimen name="profile_image_siz">100dp</dimen>
```

in normal

```
    <dimen name="profile_image_siz">120dp</dimen>
```

in large

```
    <dimen name="profile_image_siz">170dp</dimen>
```

in xlarge

```
    <dimen name="profile_image_siz">200dp</dimen>
```

and in view `android:layout_width="@dimen/profile_image_siz"`